# Why do Chars not have a `Char a => a` similar to numbers (`Num a => a`)?

Tags: haskell, types

I don't understand why when I look at the type for example of: `a = (1, 2)`
I get

```
a :: (Num a, Num b) => (a, b)
```

instead, if I look at the type of: `b = ('a', 'b')` I get

```
b :: (Char, Char)
```

and not something like:

```
b :: (Char a, Char b) => (a, b)
```

Comment: `Num` is a *typeclass*, it is a *set* of types, this looks a bit similar to what an interface is in Java/C#/... A `Char` on the other hand is a type, not a typeclass.

Comment: Have you looked at `:t 1` in `ghci`?

Comment: This comes out of the desire to use numerical literals for all sorts of numerical types. You wouldn't really want to have to write `foo :: Double; foo = fromInteger 2 * (fromRational 7.94 + pi)`. There's no real need to overload character syntax this way.

Answer (score 6):

Haskell has two types of literals: monomorphic and polymorphic. (Though it might be more accurate to say, literals can evaluate to values of monomorphic or polymorphic types.)

`'c'` is an example of a monomorphic literal; it is a value of a single type, namely `Char`.

```
> :t 'c'
'c' :: Char
```

`1`, on the other hand, is a polymorphic literal. It can be a value of any type that has a `Num` instance.

```
> :t 1
1 :: Num p => p
> :t 1 :: Int
1 :: Int :: Int
> > :t 1 :: Char

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • No instance for (Num Char) arising from the literal ‘1’
    • In the expression: 1 :: Char
```

Other polymorphic  literals include

1. Floating-point literals

   ```
   > :t 3.4
   3.4 :: Fractional p => p
   ```
2. String literals, when the `OverloadedStrings` extension is enabled.

   ```
    > :t "foo"
    "foo" :: [Char]
    > :set -XOverloadedStrings
    > :t "foo"
    "foo" :: Data.String.IsString p => p
   ```
3. List literals, when the `OverloadedLists` extension is enabled.

   ```
   > :t ['a', 'b']
   ['a', 'b'] :: [Char]
   > :set -XOverloadedLists
   > :t ['a', 'b']
   ['a', 'b'] :: (GHC.Exts.IsList l, GHC.Exts.Item l ~ Char) => l
   ```
4. Data constructors like `Nothing` (if you want to think of nullary constructors as literals)

   ```
   > :t Nothing
   Nothing :: Maybe a
   ```

   `Nothing`, for example, can be a value of type `Maybe Int`, `Maybe Char`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

[**`Num`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) is a *typeclass*, it is a *set* of types, this looks a bit similar to what an interface is in Java/C#/... The types that are members of the `Num` typeclass need to implement a certain set of functions, like in Java where types that implement the interface should implement certain methods. A `Char` on the other hand is a *type*, not a typeclass.

If you write an integer literal, it can be of any type that is a member of the `Num` typeclass, since that typeclass has a function [**`fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromInteger) that is then called to convert the integer literal to that number type.

If you write a char literal like `'a'` on the other hand, then the only type to which this can be resolved is a `Char`.

For *string* literals, you can use the [**`OverloadedStrings`** extension](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/overloaded_strings.html), in that case a string literal can take any type that is a member of the [**`IsString`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-String.html#t:IsString).

Answer (score 2):

The point of numerical literals being polymorphic is that you can use them in numerical expressions for wildly different number types.

```
Prelude> 1 + 10^12 :: Int
1000000000001
Prelude> pi + 10^12 :: Double
1.0000000000031416e12
Prelude> 1/3 + 10^12 :: Rational
3000000000001 % 3
Prelude> sqrt (-1) + 10^12 :: Data.Complex.Complex Double
1.0e12 :+ 1.0
Prelude> :m Text.LaTeX
Prelude Text.LaTeX> phi + 10^12 :: LaTeX
TeXSeq (TeXComm "phi" []) (TeXSeq (TeXRaw "+") (TeXSeq (TeXRaw "10") (TeXSeq (TeXRaw "10") (TeXSeq (TeXRaw "10") (TeXSeq (TeXRaw "10") (TeXSeq (TeXRaw "10") (TeXSeq (TeXRaw "10") (TeXSeq (TeXRaw "10") (TeXSeq (TeXRaw "10") (TeXSeq (TeXRaw "10") (TeXSeq (TeXRaw "10") (TeXSeq (TeXRaw "10") (TeXRaw "10")))))))))))))
```

Mighty useful, because such different numerical types really are used in practice.

But I don't see much point in having something like this for characters, `Char` really is the only type that makes sense. (I suppose you could argue that having a `Char8` type could sometimes be useful, but this is the Unicode age, a character outside of a string anyways occupies 64 bits, and low-level manipulations should probably be done with `Word8` and not use character literals.)

By contrast, for *strings* it does make a lot of sense to support other types apart from the old `[Char]`, that's why `-XOverloadedStrings` makes string literals polymorphic.